# Swift 2 syntax error: Cannot call value of non-function type 'Int'

Tags: swift, syntax-error, swift2

I write a function:

```
extension String {
    func size()->Int{
        return count(self.utf16)
    }
}
```

but it returns me an error:

```
Cannot call value of non-function type 'Int'
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: what is your class? is it extension?

Comment: @DanielKrom I've updated my question. Yes, it's an extension

Comment: Unrelated to your concrete problem, but is there a reason that you count the number of UTF-16 code units instead of the number of characters? – Have a look at [Strings in Swift 2](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=30) for the difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

count is the swift 1.2 way,
in swift 2.0 use `myString.characters.count` (any array can be counted that way)

so:

```
extension String {
    func size()->Int{
        return self.characters.count
    }
}
```

Comment: Where can I learn about the changes in Swift 2? I have a lot of errors so I want to fix them by myself

Comment: I googled each error - im sorry but i dont have a better idea

Answer (score 0):

`characters` is deprecated as of Swift 4. So for Swift 4 the solution would look like this-

```
extension String {
    func size()->Int{
        return self.count
    }
}
```

Comment: Sure, but this question is specifically about Swift 2.

Comment: That is true, however google hits on similar topics point to this page and information on this page (and a lot of other Swift related pages) needs updates desperately. If someone is googling a Swift topic in 2017, chances are they are looking for Swift 4 (swift 3 at best).